# ¿Puedo pasar objetos o arrays como parámetros al método replace?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, javascript-objeto, replace

Digamos que tengo un método replace como este

```
 var cadena = "hola mundo"
 var nuevoStr = cadena.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, function(pasar) {
        switch(pasar) {
            case "a":
                return "ai";
            case "e":
                return "enter";
            case "i":
                return "imes";
            case "o":
                return "ober";
            case "u":
                return "ufat";
        }
    });
    console.log(nuevoStr);
```

Mi duda es... puedo pasar como parámetros objetos o array al método replace? Por ejemplo un objeto

```
const obj = { 
     a: "a",
     e: "e",
     i: "i",
     o: "o",
     u: "u"
 }
```

Un array

```
const arr = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
```

Y en el método replace pueda hacer esto con array

```
cadena.replace(/[arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4]]/gi, function(pasar) {
        switch(pasar) {
            case "a":
                return "ai";
            case "e":
                return "enter";
            case "i":
                return "imes";
            case "o":
                return "ober";
            case "u":
                return "ufat";
        }
    });
```

con object

```
cadena.replace(/[obj.a,obj.e,obj.i,obj.o,obj.u]/gi, function(pasar) {
        switch(pasar) {
            case "a":
                return "ai";
            case "e":
                return "enter";
            case "i":
                return "imes";
            case "o":
                return "ober";
            case "u":
                return "ufat";
        }
    });
```

Esto es lo que yo creería que sería pasar objetos y arrays como parámetros al método replace, no estoy seguro si sea así o si me provocara errores de sintaxis... Esta es mi duda

Comment: No se puede, pero se puede crear una función que haga lo que quieras. Tendrías que explicar mejor lo que buscas y cual sería el resultado esperado, con un ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible pasar directamente un objeto o un array, ya que el método `replace()` espera como primer parámetro una expresión regular o una cadena de texto que se va a buscar para reemplazar.

---

Lo que si puedes hacer es crear una variable aparte y utilizar la clase `RegExp`, en donde como primer parámetro sería los elementos de tu array unidos (con `join()`), devolviendo `aeiou`, y el segundo parámetro sería la bandera `gi`, haciendo totalmente lo mismo:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`[${arr.join("")}]`, "gi");
```

Y para el caso de un objeto, puedes ingresar a sus claves con `Object.keys()`, y como esto nos devuelve un array, lo unimos con `join()`, y nos retornaría nuevamente `aeiou`:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`[${Object.keys(obj).join("")}]`, "gi");
```

**Demo con array:**

```js
const cadena = "hola mundo";
const arr = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

const regex = new RegExp(`[${arr.join("")}]`, "gi");

const nuevoStr = cadena.replace(regex, function (pasar) {
  switch (pasar) {
    case "a":
      return "ai";
    case "e":
      return "enter";
    case "i":
      return "imes";
    case "o":
      return "ober";
    case "u":
      return "ufat";
  }
});

console.log(nuevoStr);
```

**Demo con objeto:**

```js
const cadena = "hola mundo";

const obj = { 
     a: "a",
     e: "e",
     i: "i",
     o: "o",
     u: "u"
 }

const regex = new RegExp(`[${Object.keys(obj).join("")}]`, "gi");

const nuevoStr = cadena.replace(regex, function (pasar) {
  switch (pasar) {
    case "a":
      return "ai";
    case "e":
      return "enter";
    case "i":
      return "imes";
    case "o":
      return "ober";
    case "u":
      return "ufat";
  }
});

console.log(nuevoStr);
```

Comment: Interesante tu solución, la verdad no se me pasó ese detalle de las expresiones, creí que como almacenarlas en una variable de objetos o arrays podría hacerlo, entonces me sales con esta explicación y no lo sabía, buena tu explicación, habrá más maneras de hacerlo? como extra si es posible...

Comment: Si existen varias formas, pero no creo que sea más óptima que la solución que te acabo de dar...